# Can Captain Othelstan use Tiamat's Blessing of Retribution to regain health multiple times?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, npc, hit-points, hoard-of-the-dragon-queen

[Captain Othelstan](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/captain-othelstan)'s stat block (HOTDQ, p. 89) describes this benefit:

> ***Tiamat's Blessing of Retribution.*** When Othelstan takes damage that reduces him to 0 hit points, he immediately regains 20 hit points. If
>   he has 20 hit points or fewer at the end of his next turn, he dies.

For example, let's say Othelstan hits 0 HP and his Blessing heals him back to 20 HP. If a Cult healer heals him above 20 HP, he would survive. I think that's what it clearly states.

But what if he drops to 0 HP **again**, would the Blessing heal him **again**, and could the healer then heal him again to keep him going repeatedly?

I know that as the DM, I can make it work however I'd like to make it work within my story, but I'm wondering how others generally understand this power.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes, it can be used repeatedly.

The ability says nothing about it being once per combat or his needing to take a rest before it can be used again (unlike his Action Surge ability, which does states exactly that). As such, it triggers every time the condition is met.

Comment: It's even possible that it might trigger multiple times in a single round, before he promptly dies at the end of his next turn.

Comment: @nick012000 Ah, excellent point.

Comment: It's possible for it to trigger multiple times only for him to not die at the end of his next turn because the character who acts immediately before him has healing magic and puts him back above 20 HP.